# Adding New Worksheets from a List Box Collection if Specific Value Selected

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

Some background: there are 2 worksheets, one with a list of employee names/information, and one with delivery records (each delivery was made by one of the employees on the other sheet)

I have made a listbox with the employee names off the first sheet. Based on the selection from the listbox, I would like to insert a new worksheet for the employee selected that lists all the deliveries they made (off the delivery sheet). There is also an "all employees" option in the listbox that should insert a sheet for every employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be better to have your "All Employees" selection as a checkbox rather than a value in your listbox -- but that is just personal preference. If you decided to go this route, you can use the `CheckBox_Click` event to disable your listbox completely if it was checked.

Anyways, to your actual question. You can first check if the value of your list box = `All Employees` using this line of code:

```
If Me.ListBox1.Value = "All Employees" Then
```

Once you have verified the above is true, then you can get the total count of the items in your listbox with `.ListCount` and loop through each list item:

```
For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
```

For each item in the loop, ensure that you are not adding a worksheet named `All Employees`:

```
If .List(i) <> "All Employees" Then
```

and once that final test passes, create a new worksheet and name it to the value of your list box:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With Me.ListBox1
        If .Value = "All Employees" Then
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .List(i) <> "All Employees" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = .List(i)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

I assume this should be checked when you press a command button - so I've added it to that particular event.

---

### Miscellaneous Notes

- Since you didn't mention the name of your listbox, I used the generic name `ListBox1` in the code. You will have to change that to the name of your actual listbox if it's different.
- You may also have to update the name of your `CommandButton1` in the above code if the button's name you press to populate the sheets is different.

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped a lot and worked perfectly! Using that same structure I was able to add in an ELSE with the code for other listbox selections too.